# Theirs have or has?

Tags: grammar

Should I use *have* or *has* after *theirs*?

Should I say

> Theirs *have* been a long and happy marriage.

or

> Theirs *has* been a long and happy marriage.

Answer (score 1):

The subject is singular, so it should be *has*.

This is more obvious if you reorder and slightly paraphrase the sentence:

> **The marriage** of theirs **has been** long and happy.
>   → Theirs **has been a** long and happy **marriage**.

---

In theory, you could be talking about multiple couples (or separate individuals), each having a long and happy marriage. If so, the subject would be the plural *marriages*:

> Theirs **have been** long and happy **marriages**.